# AngularJS:Error that sum my result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my script for dynamical add on row.I want to sum each total result in one result.How to sum each result, that add row and remove row.

```
//start
   $scope.total = function () {

    var totalt = 0;
        angular.forEach ($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items, function (item) {
        totalt += item.quantity * item.price * (1 - item.discount / 100);
        });
        return totalt;
    };
//finish//This is script perfect work, but i have problem in my console/TypeError: Cannot read property 'Invoicetoitem' of undefined/
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <form>
                     <tr><th>№</th><th>Артикул</th><th>Мярка</th><th>Количество</th><th>Отстъпка %</th><th>Цена</th><th>Ст-ст</th><th></th></tr>
                      <tr class="clone" ng-repeat="dataItem in dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items track by $index">
                            <td class="number">{{$index+1}}</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.item.itemName"  id="{{$index+1}}"    class="tagsItem" ng-change="getItemInvoice($index+1)"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.item.solid" size="11" id="solid{{$index+1}}"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.quantity" size="10"></td>
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.discount" size="11"></td>
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.price" id="price{{$index+1}}"></td>
    <td>{{dataItem.quantity*dataItem.price*(1-dataItem.discount/100)|number:2}}</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeItem ($index)">-</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid">
    <table class="table table-condensed   table-bordered" id="cash">
       <tr><td><a class="btn btn-default" id="addnew" ng-click="addItem ()">+</a></td><td></td>
                            <td class="bank-info"></td>
                            <td>Данъчна основа </td>
    //This is my TaxBase total <td id="sum">{{total()|number:2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr><td></td><td>Словом: <input type="text" ng-model="dataInvoce.leterally"></td>
                            <td class="bank-info"></td><td>20 % ДДС</td>
    //total*0.2 my dds    <td id="dds">{{total()*0.2|number:2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td></td><td></td><td class="bank-info"></td>
                            <td>Сума за плащане</td>
      //finish general total <td id="total">{{total()+total()*0.2|number:2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10" style="border: 1px solid">
       <table class="table table-condensed  serviceColor table-bordered">
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is  my script on 70% another info is not dangerouse

Comment: can you please post a bigger html. The issue can be in inner scopes that are created when using ng-if dirrective.

Comment: $scope.dataInvoce has nothing in it.

Comment: it's not a good idea to rely upon the auto-generated `$index` when dealing with functions.  Not only is `$index+1` hard to read and understand, but `$index` doesn't represent an item's index in an array, it only represents it's position on the `ng-repeat`, and this value can change, especially if filters are used.  If you have logic that relies upon the item's array position, you should include a true indexer in the data that won't change.

Comment: I understand, this no problem for me for now !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is caused by undefined scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem object. Try initializing your array to [].

//start

```
   $scope.total = function () {
   $scope.dataInvoce = {Invoicetoitem: {items: []}}; //add this line
    var totalt = 0;
        angular.forEach ($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items, function (item) {
        totalt += item.quantity * item.price * (1 - item.discount / 100);
        });
        return totalt;
    };
```

Comment: This  script block my all data.

Comment: What do you mean by it "blocks" all of your data?   Also, when you get the data back from your ajax call, you need to update "$scope.dataInvoice.Invoicetoitem.items" with the result.

Comment: I have big form filled with fields, that insert your script, my fields disappears.